# Cytoscape.js in an ESM environment with npm: Import problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules, cytoscape.js

**How can I import cytoscape.js into my npm ESM project?**

Versions I use are:  npm: '8.1.4',  node: '14.15.3'.

My package.json defines that I want to do ESM:
`"type": "module",`

The cytoscape.js documentation states the following:

> To install Cytoscape.js via npm: `npm install cytoscape`
>
> To use Cytoscape.js in an ESM environment with npm (e.g. Webpack or Node.js with the esm package): `import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';`

I followed the instructions. However, the import results in the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../node_modules/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.cjs.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Well, that is correct since the commonjs version was loaded. But in an ESM environment `cytoscape.esm.js` should be loaded instead of `cytoscape.cjs.js`. However, `node_modules/cytoscape/package.json` says to use the commonjs version: `"main": "dist/cytoscape.cjs.js",`

So I tried to import the ESM version directly in my code:

`import cytoscape from './../../node_modules/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.esm.js';`

Cytoscape.js is now imported. However, I get the followup error in an dependent package:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../heap/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'` in line `cytoscape.esm.js:24`

I'm kind of stuck now. Other related questions did not help so far. I'll be happy for any suggestion or even solution. Thanks in advance!